# how to work on offline 3d maps using nutiteq in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, nutiteq

I am sorry if this question has been asked before.But I am getting trouble while working on offline 3d maps.I have downloaded the source code from github:

https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d

Its working well but on its offlineActivity nothing happens,the map doesn't work.Please help as i searched a lot but no working code found.If any of you have a working code then its highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.. !

Following screenshot is asking for the .nml or .dae file.After selecting either of the file .nmldb image is shown(here a man) on map.If Internet connection is on,it shows the 3d map and if the connection is off, only the .nml image is shown..
[image]

[image]    [image]                                              Following are the errors which I am getting:

```
com.nutiteq.rasterdatasources.HTTPRasterDataSource: failed to load tile. Unable to resolve host "otile1.mqcdn.com": No address associated with hostname
 DataSourceFetchTask: no tile data
```

This is the code which is working fine if Internet connectivity is ON and if its OFf, the above error is shown and i get only a mans image without the map(screenshot3):

```
RasterDataSource dataSource = new HTTPRasterDataSource(new EPSG3857(), 0, 18, "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png");
        RasterLayer mapLayer = new RasterLayer(dataSource, 0);
        mapView.getLayers().setBaseLayer(mapLayer);
```

Comment: Can u clarify your question in detail. Like putting up a screenshot so that i can view.Where you are finding issues.

Comment: ya sure wait will send the screenshots..

Comment: @priyanka..hmm,,you can do one thing add me on my skype id tushar_sahni27... I am leaving for the day.Waiting for your screenshots.

Comment: @Tushar I am sorry, but I am not on skype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code means that you use online base map data source from MapQuest:

```
RasterDataSource dataSource = new HTTPRasterDataSource(new EPSG3857(), 0, 18, "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png");
```

You should replace it with offline Data Source. There are different options, see Nutiteq wiki page https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Offline-map-tiles for the Data Sources what you can get with AdvancedLayers project.

Comment: Thanks sir,It works with the packagedMapLayer.I also tried using storedMapLayer but got stucked in the parameters of storedMapLayer while defining the path.   Also,as per my requirements,my data is quite large please suggest me which layer to use? Thanks in advance..

Comment: is that mean the... " MBTilesRasterDataSource dataSource = new MBTilesRasterDataSource(new EPSG3857(), 0, 19, "/sdcard/mymaps.mbtiles", false, this);
            RasterLayer mbLayer = new RasterLayer(dataSource, file.hashCode());" part @JaakL ?

Comment: @gumuruh - Yes, MBTilesRasterDataSource is the most common offline map data source options. StoredMapLayer is deprecated since Nutiteq 2.4 and not suggested.

Comment: i see... that's why i'm unable to find where that class was coming from! THanks @JaakL,... oh ya, one more thing. Do you get any other alternative rather than using nutiteq? :D